# convert the time into US different time zones

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay

I have a requirement where i am fetching the date and time from database. For USA there are multiple timezone. So i want to convert the time which is coming from DB into current time zone.

i.e I want something like, in DB time is stored as GMT format but want to convert that time to PST for PST user, MST for MST User, CST for CST User and EST for EST User.

Edit::
Somehow i am able to fetch the time for different time zone.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar localTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        localTime.setTime(new Date());
        System.out.println("PST::"+getTimeByTimezone("PST",localTime));
        System.out.println("MST::"+getTimeByTimezone("MST",localTime));
        System.out.println("CST::"+getTimeByTimezone("CST",localTime));
        System.out.println("EST::"+getTimeByTimezone("EST",localTime));
    }

    public static String getTimeByTimezone(String timeZone,Calendar localTime){     

        Calendar indiaTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
        indiaTime.setTimeInMillis(localTime.getTimeInMillis());
        int hour = indiaTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minute = indiaTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = indiaTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int year = indiaTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        //System.out.printf("India time: %02d:%02d:%02d %02d\n", hour, minute, second, year);
        return hour+":"+minute; 

    }
```

But i want to convert the time which is already published on the page.

Comment: I suspect you don't actually want PST - I suspect you want "Pacific Time" etc. So, do you have the appropriate time zone? What have you tried so far, and what's happened? This question is unclear at the moment. A [mcve] would really help...

Comment: What do you mean by *"But i want to convert the time which is already published on the page"*? The question leading up to that is about converting GMT time from database to user time zone, so what does that have to do with a time that is *already* "published", whatever that means?

Comment: Certainly the GMT format is getting publish on the page, which i need to convert it into the different time zone

Comment: I updated my answer to give you an example of a method using `ZonedDateTime`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `ZonedDateTime` in **Java 8**:

```
public String getZonedDateString(Date date, ZoneId targetZoneId) {
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneOffset.UTC; // This should be the zone of your database
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), zoneId);
    ZonedDateTime newZonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(targetZoneId);
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyy hh:mm") .format(newZonedDateTime);
}
```

Usage:

```
Date date = new Date();
ZoneOffset newZoneId = ZoneOffset.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("MST"));
String dateString = getZonedDateString(date, newZoneId);
```

See here how to use [ZoneOffset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)

---

**Pre Java 8:**

```
public String getZonedDateString(Date date, TimeZone targetZone) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyy hh:mm");
    format.setTimeZone(targetZone);
    return format.format(date);
}
```

Usage:

```
TimeZone targetZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST");
String dateString = getZonedDateString(date, targetZone);
```

See here how to use [TimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

Comment: I am using JDK7, can we use any other class insteead of ZonedDateTIme?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It worked perfectly fine to me.
Now i am able to convert GMT to PST time zone.

```
DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        gmtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = gmtFormat.parse("11:10");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DateFormat pstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        pstFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));

        String timedd = pstFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(pstFormat.format(date));
```